# pandas._libs.tslib.NaTType is different from pandas.tslib.NaTType

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In `pandas`, why `pandas._libs.tslib.NaTType` is different from `pandas.tslib.NaTType`, I thought `_libs.tslib.NaTType` exposes to `tslib.NaTType`? `val_type` is `pandas._libs.tslib.NaTType`,

```
issubclass(val_type, pd.tslib.NaTType)

False

issubclass(val_type, pd._libs.tslib.NaTType)

True
```

Also when I tried to display an error message,

```
raise TypeError(
        'type error for value {} of type {}'.format(val, val_type))
```

it only displays as

```
type error for value {} of type {}
```

I am wondering how to fix it.

UPDATE

Running `Python 3.5.2` on `Linux Mint 18.1 X64`

updated `pandas` using

```
sudo pip3 install pandas --upgrade

Successfully installed numpy-1.13.3 pandas-0.21.0 pytz-2017.3 six-1.11.0
```

show `pandas` version using

```
pip3 show pandas
Version: 0.21.0

pip3 show numpy
Version: 1.10.4
```

updated `numpy` to `1.13.3`, using

```
sudo pip3 install numpy --upgrade
```

show `numpy` version using

```
sudo pip3 show numpy
Version: 1.13.3
```

running the same code, it still shows `False`. when `issubclass(val_type, pd.tslib.NaTType)` or `val_type is pd.tslib.NaTType`.

Comment: What is your pandas version? on `0.21.0` I get `True` for this

Comment: @EdChum I am using ` 0.20.3` , seems I need an update on it

Comment: It seems like a silly bug to me, I'd update to `0.21.0` if you can

Comment: I updated `pandas` to `0.21.0`, but it still shows `False` when `val_type is pd.tslib.NaTType` or `issubclass(val_type, pd.tslib.NaTType)`

Comment: What's your numpy, python and OS? Mine is numpy: `1.11.3` python 3.6, Win7 64-bit

Comment: `numpy` - `1.10.4`, `python` - `3.5.2`, `linux mint 18.1`, when I updated `pandas` to `0.21.0`, it showed `Successfully installed numpy-1.13.3 pandas-0.21.0 pytz-2017.3 six-1.11.0`

Comment: You could try upgrading `numpy` otherwise not sure